# New data overwrote previous data in NSMutableArray (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to create a series of UIButton out of an array of points.
aCoord is the array of points. For each points, I used its x,y coordinates to generate a UIButton. Each button is then stored in the buttonArray.

```
            let aCoord:NSMutableArray = self.homeViewData[self.number]["annotations"] as NSMutableArray
            var buttonObjects: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
            var coordx:Float = Float()
            var coordy:Float = Float()


                for item in aCoord {

                    coordx = item[0] as Float
                    coordy = item[1] as Float

                    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

                    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(coordx),CGFloat(coordy), 60, 60)
                    self.button.setImage(UIImage (named: "tagbutton.png"), forState: .Normal)
                    self.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

                    buttonObjects.addObject(self.button)
                    self.dialogView.addSubview(self.button)

                }
```

but somehow the new buttons always overwrote the previous button, like this:

```
<UIButton: 0x7f9269d73bc0; frame = (159 300; 60 60); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9269d72d90>>
(
    "<UIButton: 0x7f9269d73bc0; frame = (159 300; 60 60); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9269d72d90>>"
)
1
<UIButton: 0x7f9269d73bc0; frame = (154 430.5; 60 60); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9269d72d90>>
(
    "<UIButton: 0x7f9269d73bc0; frame = (154 430.5; 60 60); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9269d72d90>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7f9269d73bc0; frame = (154 430.5; 60 60); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9269d72d90>>"
)
2
```

The button with coordinates (154, 430.5) overwrote the one with (159, 300).
Saw similar questions in Obj-C, tried their methods but doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use `self.button` and not just `button` (in the loop)?

Comment: ops. I didn't init the button inside the loop, but I forgot to remove the "self" after I did that...it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you were adding the same button again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add `self` before `button` in your loop because button is a locally created variable and not the property of the class. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `self.button` in your `for` loop. Just use `button`.